# type="hidden" textinput controls are being shown / IIS7, MS Server 2008 R2 is the configuration

Tags: asp.net

Please help me with this issue, `type="hidden"` textinput controls are being shown.

Environment: IIS7, Windows Server 2008 R2

It works fine on Windows Server 2003, Win7 Ultimate, please guide me, if you can think of anything which can cause this problem,

Control code:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="SopFunctionIDTextBox0" runat="server" type="hidden" 
                        Text="Do not show"
                        value='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("SopFunctionID")) %>' />
```

When it is rendering it is showing the following in the source code:

Rendered from the problem server:

```
 <input name="ListView1$ctrl1$SopFunctionIDTextBox0" type="text" id="ListView1_ctrl1_SopFunctionIDTextBox0" type="hidden" value="101" />
```

For some reason it is adding `type="text"`

Rendered from working  server:

```
<input name="ListView1$ctrl1$SopFunctionIDTextBox0" id="ListView1_ctrl1_SopFunctionIDTextBox0"   type="hidden" value="101" />
```

Thanks in advance

BSS

Answer (score 3):

You should use an `asp:HiddenField` if that's what you want.